# Syndication Feed XML Exception during load function

Tags: c#, xml, atom-feed

XML Exception occured while loading atom url :

code:

```
XMLReader reader =XmlReader.Create("urlstring");

SyndicationFeed feed =SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
```

exception:

> $exception    {"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position
>   1."}  System.Exception {System.Xml.XmlException}

Atom URL Content:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
...
</feed>
```

Do we need to have XMLVersion as first line in the atom url if not how do we deal with it?.
 Any pointers to resolution appreciated .

Comment: U can try http://validator.w3.org/appc/ to validate your RSS   and you  can add try-catch with XmlException as well...

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem with RSS feeds. .Net Syndication does not read all feed formats.
Instead of using .Net SyndicationFeed I went for Argotic Syndication Framework

It works well and you can download it from codeplex
http://argotic.codeplex.com/

Hope that helps

Comment: It is a dead project anyway current  Argotic Syndication Framework 2008.0.2.0

Comment: @Dimi - It's not worked on anymore but it's very capable and the rss/atom formats have not changed since Argotic's launch.  It's a viable library.